# when I create a page with a /blog permalink the css gets messed up

Tags: permalinks, css, blog, parent-theme

When I create a page with a default template and parent set to no parent, with the permalinks name being `sitename/blog` the css on that page gets messed up(including the admin bar is all messed up), if I change the permalinks structure to `sitename/blogs` it works perfectly fine. Also if I change the parent to another one of the pages with either permalinks name, the css works fine. Does /blog permalink register a weird parent or do something I am not aware other than the defaults. I have other pages with the same setup other than there permalinks name that work fine.

You can view the broken site [here](http://goodmorningmoon.ca) password: springy88
**click the blog link**

Thanks in advance!
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your wordpress menu use another class instead of "blog" for the blog item, cause your theme has a function that add a similar class to the body so it's creating a conflict in there, try erasing your blog class for you to notice.

Also the app.css if for ur custom css :), no need to use both.

Comment: I deleted the blog class under appearance menus, and it still looks the same. The only way I can get it to fix is by changing the blog permalink or parent.

Comment: its working now, with no class and with a new class. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: no problem! watch out with your margins and the mobile size of the layout